# Bootstrap typeahead multiple json data binding

Tags: javascript, json, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

As you can see followed code, i'm trying to bind both values id and name what returned on json data to typeahead but it's not working, it's only working if json data returns only one value such as `{"name":"Mjora"}`

**json.js**

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Chima"},{"id":2,"name":"Mpula"}]
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <title>Typeahead</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/releases/latest/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            var users = new Bloodhound({
                datumTokenizer: function (d) { 
                    return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.name); 
                },
                queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
                prefetch: "/json.js"
            });

            users.initialize();

            $('.loc').typeahead(null, {
                name: 'fullname',
                displayKey: 'name',
                source: users.ttAdapter()
            });             

        });
    </script>
    <body>
        <input type="text" class="loc" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you say it's "not working", what is actually happening, and how does that differ from what you expected?

Comment: in this way i don't bind to returning JSON data (id and name).so i look forward to your suggestions because i didn't find any solution on google.